# With eclipse debugging feature, can multiple users connect to same application deployed in same machine/port?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

I have an application deployed into WebSphere which many in my team might want to remote debug, simultaneously. Is it possible?

Comment: No allowed by JDWP, as soon as the first debugger is connected you'll see the listening port is gone.